# Mongoose Nested Schema Validation Errors

Tags: mongoose-schema

I am fairly new to the MEAN stack, so perhaps I am doing something incredibly silly.

I have several defined schemas (BlogEntry, ForumPost) that both require the same nested schema (in this case Comment) so I have moved the Comment schema to its own file to avoid any code duplication.

Looking just at the example of BlogEntry, I have the following in my blog.js model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BlogEntry = new Schema({
    title: String,
    thumbnailUrl: String,
    content: String,
    comments: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Comment'
        }
    ]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


var Blog = new Schema({
    createdBy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    headerImageUrl: String,
    description: String,
    blogEntries: [BlogEntry]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', Blog);
```

and the Comment schema is contained in comment.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Comment = new Schema({
    commentText:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postedBy:  {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    parentComment: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', Comment);
```

My router for handling Blog information contains the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Blog = require('../models/blog');
var Verify = require('./verify');
var blogRouter = express.Router();
blogRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

blogRouter.route('/')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
    Blog.find(req.query) 
        .populate('createdBy')
        .exec(function(err, blog) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.json(blog);
        });
})

.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req, res, next) {
    req.body.createdBy = req.decoded._id;
    Blog.create(req.body, function(err, blog) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        console.log("Blog created");
        var id = blog._id;
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Added the blog with id: ' + id);
    });
});

module.exports = blogRouter;
```

When the Comments schema is in a separate file, and I post the following request, I get a validation error:

```
{
    "name": "A Cheesemaker's Adventure",
    "headerImageUrl": "images/cheeseAdven.png",
    "description": "The story of a man's transformation from a miserable, downtrodden software engineer to a bouyant, joy-filled cheesemaker.",
    "blogEntries" : [
        {
          "title": "I like cheese",
          "content": "Here is my story...blah blah blah...",
          "comments": [
              {
                 "commentText": "Who's is this guy kidding!"
              }
          ]
        }
    ]
}


<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Blog validation failed</h1><h2></h2><pre>ValidationError: Blog validation failed
    at MongooseError.ValidationError (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:22:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1410:32)
    at EmbeddedDocument.invalidate (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:190:19)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document.set (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:703:10)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document.set (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:548:18)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:67:10)
    at new EmbeddedDocument (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:30:12)
    at EmbeddedDocument (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:27:17)
    at DocumentArray.cast (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:254:22)
    at DocumentArray.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:628:12)
    at model.Document.set (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:695:18)
    at model.Document.set (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:548:18)
    at model.Document (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:67:10)
    at model.Model (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:41:12)
    at new model (C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3175:11)
    at C:\Development\hcj-express\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:1847:51</pre></body></html>
```

However, if I get rid of the comment.js file, and move the Comment schema into the blog.js file, like so, I can post the exact same message as listed above, the validation error goes away, and I successfully post the data.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Comment = new Schema({
    commentText:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postedBy:  {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    parentComment: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

var BlogEntry = new Schema({
    title: String,
    thumbnailUrl: String,
    content: String,
    comments: [Comment]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

var Blog = new Schema({
    createdBy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    headerImageUrl: String,
    description: String,
    blogEntries: [BlogEntry]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', Blog);
```

Sooo...what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

When you're working using separate file, you need to guarantee that 'Comments' schema is being loaded before 'BlogEntry' Schema.

You can do it just adding `require('./comment.js')` at the top of  BlogEntry.js. Example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Comment = require('./comment.js');

var BlogEntry = new Schema({
    title: String,
    thumbnailUrl: String,
    content: String,
    comments: [Comment]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Comment: Made the change you mentioned, deployed to the server and still getting the same error.  Interestingly enough, the nested reference to User works fine, even though that is in a different file, and is not explicitly required in this schema file.

Comment: If you're used User in another point in your code (problably into verifyOrdinaryUser function). Then previous 'require' added it to the mongoose cache.

Keep ```require('./comment.js')``` and try to change ```comments: [Comment]``` to 
```comments: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
}]```

Comment: I would agree with that @Rafael, this is the first use of comment.js so it should be in a require statement. I have tried using both `comments: [Comment]` and `comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]` but get the same error in both cases.